# Filter contacts in outlook API using startswith()

Tags: odata, office365, outlook-restapi

I am trying to get a list of contacts that are filtered by email address from Microsoft Outlook API (Contact API). The url I am using for the request is:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts/?$filter=EmailAddresses/any(email: startswith(email/Address,'ab'))
```

The filter property `$filter=EmailAddresses/any(email: email/Address eq  'ab')` is working fine.

Here `EmailAddresses` field is a list containing name, address fields.

> **UPDATE**
>
> Original response :
>
> ```
>     {
>       "@odata.context": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me/Contacts",
>       "value": [
>         {
>           ..................................
>           ..................................
>
>           "DisplayName": "Abhishek R",
>           "GivenName": "Abhishek",
>           "Initials": null,
>           "MiddleName": null,
>           "NickName": null,
>           "Surname": "R",
>           "Title": null,
>           "YomiGivenName": null,
>           "YomiSurname": null,
>           "YomiCompanyName": null,
>           "Generation": null,
>           "ImAddresses": [],
>           "JobTitle": null,
>           "CompanyName": null,
>           "Department": null,
>           "OfficeLocation": null,
>           "Profession": null,
>           "BusinessHomePage": null,
>           "AssistantName": null,
>           "Manager": null,
>           "HomePhones": [],
>           "MobilePhone1": null,
>           "BusinessPhones": [],
>           "SpouseName": null,
>           "PersonalNotes": null,
>           "Children": [],
>           "EmailAddresses": [
>             {
>               "Name": "abhishek@gmail.com",
>               "Address": "abhishek@gmail.com"
>             },
>             {
>               "Name": "abcdef@gmail.com",
>               "Address": "abcdef@gmail.com"
>             }
>           ],
>           "HomeAddress": {},
>           "BusinessAddress": {},
>           "OtherAddress": {}
>         }
>       ]
>     }
> ```

The response I got is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidUrlQueryFilter",
    "message": "The query filter contains one or more invalid nodes."
  }
}
```

Looking for a solution to this.